# testfor a cocoa bean in a player inventory

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have been trying to figure this one for about an hour now, yet I still can find out how to detect cocoa beans in a player inventory in 1.11.2. The command I used was:

```
/testfor awesomeianman {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:dye",Damage:3}]}
```

Whenever I tried this, it didn't have an output! Could someone please help me, and tell me if the command is completely wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I filter items with a certain enchantement?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/235358/how-can-i-filter-items-with-a-certain-enchantement)

Answer (score 1):

When testing for pre-existing data, you must specify that data as it's saved. The `Damage` tag is saved as a short, so you append the numerical value with an "s":

```
/testfor awesomeianman {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:dye",Damage:3s}]}
```

Comment: wait, so I just tried this, nothing happened. are you sure this is for 1.11.2?

Comment: @BACONISDABEST2COOL4U Works fine for me, provided I replace your name with mine. Ensure your command block is actually activating, and provide any errors it gives.