# Minecraft 1.13.1 Inventory Count NBT Tag

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was trying to detect whether a player had a certain amount of items in their inventory.

I can detect if a player has an item in their inventory like this:

```
/execute as @a[nbt={Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:command_block"}]}] run say hi
```

But I thought there was a Count tag too. So I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
/execute as @a[nbt={Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:command_block",Count:5}]}] run say hi
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [How can I filter items with a certain enchantement?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/235358/how-can-i-filter-items-with-a-certain-enchantement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NBT setting can often be done without types, namespaces or similar, but testing has to be exact:

/execute as @a[nbt={Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:command_block",Count:5**b**}]}]

Also, keep in mind that this will not match a player with e.g. one stack of 2 and one stack with 3 command blocks.