# Executing at fireworks entity with specific nbt

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a command that executes at a firework_rocket entity with specific nbt (In this case explosion colours), and runs a certain command whenever such a firework is present, however, nothing happens.

Here is the /execute command in question

```
execute at @e[type=firework_rocket,nbt={FireworksItem:{id:firework_rocket,Count:1,tag:{Fireworks:{Explosions:[{Colors:[I;11743532,3887386]}]}}}}] run say doot
```

If this worked, it should react by saying doot constantly every time any single firework rocket with a matching explosion was flying. It doesn't.

The nbt should be identical to the one summoned with this command (I checked)

```
/summon firework_rocket ~ ~1 ~ {FireworksItem:{id:firework_rocket,Count:1,tag:{Fireworks:{Explosions:[{Colors:[I;11743532,3887386]}]}}}}
```

And it should also react whenever a player used the rocket given as an item with this command

```
/give @p firework_rocket{Fireworks:{Explosions:[{Colors:[I;11743532,3887386]}]}} 1
```

Not a single of these commands works, and I checked that the nbt is identical for each of them, yet nothing happens.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I filter items with a certain enchantement?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/235358/how-can-i-filter-items-with-a-certain-enchantement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to match the formats exactly, for example `1b` instead of `1`. You can check the NBT with `data get`.

Comment: Oooh, thanks a lot! I simply need to change it to id:"minecraft:firework_rocket" instead of just id:firework_rocket and it worked! Thanks!